# R dplyr: min max function not working in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an issue with dplyr I cannot resolve. Also I do not have a full workable example, since the problem only occurs with the full set of data (that I cannot share with you).

I do the following:

```
t %>% group_by(id, add=TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(minbplevel = min(ref, na.rm=T)
       ,maxbplevel = max(ref, na.rm=T)
       ) %>% filter(id %in% c(caseA,caseB))
```

Which results in

```
id         minbplevel maxbplevel
(dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1 B            33.0       73.0
2 A            39.4       80.4
```

But when I do

```
t %>% group_by(id, add=TRUE) %>% 
mutate(minbplevel = min(ref, na.rm=T)
       ,maxbplevel = max(ref, na.rm=T)
       ) %>% filter(id %in% c(caseA,caseB))
```

It results in:

```
   id   Level refparmax refparmin   ref meanbptest minbplevel maxbplevel
(dbl)   (chr)     (int)     (int) (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1  B          0SD        69        68  49.0   52.00000         33         73
2  B       min1SD        69        68  41.0   52.00000         33         73
3  B       min2SD        69        68  33.0   52.00000         33         73
4  B      plus1SD        69        68  59.0   52.00000         33         73
5  B      plus2SD        69        68  73.0   52.00000         33         73
6  A          0SD       100        95  56.4   35.33333         NA         NA
7  A       min1SD       100        95  47.4   35.33333         NA         NA
8  A       min2SD       100        95  39.4   35.33333         NA         NA
9  A      plus1SD       100        95  67.4   35.33333         NA         NA
10 A      plus2SD       100        95  80.4   35.33333         NA         NA
```

Why the NA's in case A are produced, I have no clue. It seems that each time I try it on a subset of the data, the second case with data is the problem, but that is just a hunch.
It is only one case of the 18850 that gives this issue, but there is nothing identifiable that makes the problem case different than the rest.

Please advice what I can try to do to solve this? 
I can think of workarounds, creating the summarized data and then merging the result with the original data. But I thought that dplyr would allow me to do this in one step.

I tried removing or adding the add = TRUE option. That does not make any difference.

Maybe I am using this in the wrong way.

---

Based on comment I tried:

```
subset(with(t,aggregate(ref~id, t, FUN= min, na.rm=TRUE, na.action= na.pass)),id %in% c(caseA,caseB))
```

Which results in

```
      id  ref
4 B 33.0
5 A 39.4
```

---

I have to mask some parts of the data.

```
dput(head(subset(t,id %in% c(caseA,caseB)) , 12))
```

gives:

Again I replaced the actual id's with variables caseB and caseA. Also this is not the full dataset in which the problem occurs.

```
structure(list(id = c(caseB, caseB, caseB, caseB, caseB, 
caseA, caseA, caseA, caseA, caseA), Level = c("0SD", "min1SD", 
"min2SD", "plus1SD", "plus2SD", "0SD", "min1SD", "min2SD", "plus1SD", 
"plus2SD"), refparmax = c(69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L), refparmin = c(68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L), ref = c(49, 41, 33, 59, 73, 56.4, 47.4, 
39.4, 67.4, 80.4), meanbptest = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 35.3333333333333, 
35.3333333333333, 35.3333333333333, 35.3333333333333, 35.3333333333333
)), .Names = c("id", "Level", "refparmax", "refparmin", "ref", 
"meanbptest"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), vars = list(id), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:4, 5:9), group_sizes = c(5L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(
    id = c(caseB, caseA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), vars = list(id), drop = TRUE, .Names = "id"))
```

Comment: Can you try it on a base R solution to check if that is based on the `dplyr` mutate or not? i.e. `aggregate(ref~id, t, FUN= min, na.rm=TRUE, na.action= na.pass)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get an error when I run either option due to lack of definition of `caseA` and `caseB`. When I remove the filter, all values occur after the `mutate`. You need to post using `dput(head(t, 12))`

Comment: With the edit my version of R chokes on the unquoted `caseA` and `caseB` even with pkg:dplyr loaded. I think you should retrace the steps leading up to this structure.

Comment: There was an issue with `mutate` and `NA` awhile back that has been fixed in the [development version of dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr).  Have you tried using that?

Comment: Installing the "development version" as of today does not fix the error I am getting. Even after assigning `caseA` as "caseA" and `caseB` as "caseB" which then allows the parsing of that structure and assignment to a variable name, that symbol value cannot then be handled by the `print` method for class="grouped_df".

Comment: Please dont fall over the example I provided. Since I need to strip this from any identifiable info. Replace it with 1 and 2 or something, or assign a variable caseA and caseB with 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: @aosmith : unfortunately i cannot install the dev version of dplyr due to workstation restrictions. Do you have a description of the mutate and NA issue? Maybe I can find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If I replace all NA's in the ref column with zeros the mutate step is working fine. As aosmith suggested, it has probably something to do with the mutate and NA issue that is fixed in the developement version of dplyr.

I cannot test this suggestion due to workstation restrictions though. So I will work around the issue, with the NA replacement step, and process the zero values after the summary steps.